# Run only a specific branch on a specific hour on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I m using jenkins pipeline with a Jenkinsfile.
I want to trigger a build of one specific branch on a specific hour of the day.
The problem is when using the multi-branch pipeline option are sooo limited.
There is only a

> Scan Multibranch Pipeline with defaults Triggers

that trigger the build of all branches periodically (not even on a specific hour of the day).
Is there a solution to build one specific branch on a specific hour ? and is there a way to have a rich amout of configurations in multi-branch pipeline project type ? (like when starting a free-style project)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure there are those options.

Are you talking about scripted pipeline?

### Scripted Pipeline

Please check the pipeline `properties` step.
You can use it to configure the actual options like time-trigger and the like.

Think of the multibranch not as a job but as a folder containing one job per branch. For each branch those options can be set using the `properties` step. They cannot be set using the GUI, you can only view them.

Best will be using the snippet generator to generate the required options for one branch as an example.

Having that you can - depending on what you need - either have the same Jenkinsfile for all branches and check `env.BRANCH_NAME` to set the properties per branch with some if or switch conditionals.

Or you can adjust this part of the Jenkinsfile for each branch that needs different options as compared to the master branch.

### Declarative Pipeline

Unfortunately I do not have much experience yet using declarative Pipeline.
However there’s the `options` clause which can set build properties similar to the properties step.
Not sure whether the properties step itself would be usable as well.

### Alternative Solution using Trigger Job

In case you need something else you could still create a separate Pipeline job which only takes care of triggering the correct branch at the right time for the desired job. Should not be too hard using the scripted pipeline. You just would need somehow to figure out the current time so you know which branch to trigger. For the trigger use the `build` step. For the project to trigger use `multibranch job name/branch name` syntax.

### Solution using per-Branch trigger jobs

You may also create a separate trigger job, one per branch. Those jobs could be itself triggered at different times and just trigger the target job’s branch using the `build` step.

Answer (score -2):

Or you can use input variable for branches in your pipeline.

for e.g.

```
stage('Build') {
    input 'Proceed to build?'
    sh 'mvn  -f abc/pom.xml clean install -U'
}
```